# Django delete database record when HTML button is clicked

Tags: django

I'm trying to create a button located in an HTML table that when clicked will delete a record (article in this case) from the database.  I pass the articles pk like I've done with other links, but I can't figure out how make the deletion happen.  I've searched online and the help files, but I'm new and really need someone to lay it all out for me. What should the URL and View look?

HTML:

```
<a href="{% url 'remove_article', article_pk=articles.pk %}"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove-circle"></span></a>
```

URLS (second url):

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.CompanyList.as_view(), name='company_list'),
    url(r'^company/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/$', views.CompanyDetails.as_view(), name='company_details'),
    url(r'^company/(?P<pk>[0-9]+)/remove$', views.CompanyDetails.delete_article(), name='remove_article'),
    url(r'^company/transcript/(?P<transcript_id>[0-9]+)/$', views.TranscriptList.as_view(), name='transcript_details'),
]
```

VIEW (for this page):

```
class CompanyDetails(generic.DetailView):
    model = Company
    template_name = 'company_details.html'
    context_object_name = 'articles'

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Articles.objects.filter(company_id=self.kwargs.get('company_id')).order_by('-date')

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
        context = super(CompanyDetails, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['articles'] = Articles.objects.filter(company_id=pk).order_by('-date')
        context['company'] = Company.objects.filter(id=pk)
        context['transcripts'] = Transcripts.objects.filter(company_id=pk)
        return context

    # Here is where I'm struggling...
    def delete_article():
        article = Articles.objects.get(pk='article_pk')
        article.delete()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Django has a built in [DeleteView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/class-based-views/generic-editing/#django.views.generic.edit.DeleteView), so probably best to use that. Also, for security reasons, you really should use a form so that you can POST to this view. (Which the linked DeleteView provides an example of.)

Comment: I read that before but it didn't make sense to me.  Finally figured it follow this example on YouTube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5Ez2NXOX9zY